# How to configure Jenkins build name to conditionally include some text?

Tags: jenkins

I have an input parameter named Rollback.

Currently I have configured the name like this -

```
#${BUILD_NUMBER}-${deployment_group}-${branch_name}-rollback-${rollback}
```

So, depending on whether user opts to rollback or not, following are the names that are currently being generated and what I would like to have -

```
#348-cd-test-group-master-rollback-no  (currently)  
#348-cd-test-group-master (rollback info should be normally present)

#348-cd-test-group-master-rollback-yes (currently)  
#348-cd-test-group-master-rollback (only rollback string should be present if rollback case).
```

Comment: Do you use FreeStyle job or Pipeline job? Or something else?

Comment: @izzekil I am a newbie and do not know the difference between the two. How to check if an existing Jenkins job/project is freestyle or pipeline? I can see the options while creating a "new item". But how to check for an existing project?